# Concatenating arrays according to a column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of 2d arrays in python. For each 2d array the last column indicates an ID. Now I would like to join (perhaps with numpy) the rows of the arrays according to the ID (the last column).

So for example the rows with ID 1 should be concatenated. Each ID only appears once per array. In addition, the ID (last column) as well as the second last column should only be written at the very end of the concatenated array (i.e. only once).

How can this be done?

Comment: [`Add a sample case`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a good `join` method for just this role. It's easiest to use if your id columns are your `DataFrame`'s indices. Assume two of your 2d arrays are `adata` and `bdata`, their corresponding ids are `a_ids` and `b_ids`. (If you're dealing with only integer data sets, and your ids are also integers, they can go in the final column of a numpy array. But often numpy deals with floating point values, and ids are often strings not integers. In either of those common cases, better or even necessary to keep the ids separate, since numpy arrays are homogeneous.)

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(adata, index=a_ids)
b = pd.DataFrame(bdata, index=b_ids)
```

Now you have something like:

[image]

To join:

```py
ab = a.join(b, lsuffix='a', rsuffix='b', how='outer')
```

Yielding:

[image]

This is an outer join, meaning it returns the union of all records, including situations where an id occurs in just one or the other data set. If you want just matches on both inputs (or if all your data sets have equivalent ids), you can use `how='inner'` for the tighter intersection join.

If you want a numpy array back rather than a `DataFrame`, that's easy:

```py
ab.values
```

Yields:

```py
array([[-0.68185189,  2.06517757,  0.49309249,  0.56342363],
       [ 0.18518231, -2.93460494,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.06447249, -0.30244753,  2.46605889, -0.28043202],
       [ 0.62137062,  0.10228747, -0.21668058, -1.07091799],
       [-0.37247196, -1.5782334 ,         nan,         nan],
       [-1.0523353 , -0.52960419,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.13638979,  0.92173315,         nan,         nan]])
```

And for the joined indices:

```py
ab.index.values
```

Gives:

```py
array([1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007])
```

So while you have danced through Pandas and benefited from its high-level join operation (which works even if your data sets are different sizes, the ids included are not exactly the same, and even if the ids fall in different order), you're right back in NumPy values if you want to work with those.

Final note, if you're using NumPy for integer values, so that your ids are already embedded as the final column in each dataset, just adjust the `DataFrame` constructors to grab the data like this:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(adata[:, :-1], index=adata[:, -1])
b = pd.DataFrame(bdata[:, :-1], index=bdata[:, -1])

                     # data                 ids
                     # ^ all rows           ^ all rows
                     #    ^ all but last col   ^ just last col
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example using `pandas`, since no data or code were originally provided:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# let the last column in these 2-d arrays be the "ID" column
arr1 = np.array([[0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,0,0,2], [1,1,1,2,3]])
arr2 = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1], [2,1,0,0,2], [2,2,1,2,3]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2)

# Again, a minimal example, but the column at index 4 in these
# DataFrames is the ID column, so we can merge on 4 to get our result
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy` version with `@robot's` sample data, uses `argsort` to collect rows by last column value:

```
In [28]: arr1 = np.array([[0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,0,0,2], [1,1,1,2,3]])
In [29]: arr2 = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1], [2,1,0,0,2], [2,2,1,2,3]])
In [30]: arr=np.concatenate((arr1,arr2),axis=0)
In [31]: arr
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 3]])
In [32]: idx=np.argsort(arr[:,-1])
In [33]: idx
Out[33]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5], dtype=int32)
In [34]: arr[idx,:]
Out[34]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 3]])
```

> In addition, the ID (last column) as well as the second last column should only be written at the very end of the concatenated array (i.e. only once).

this requirment, if I understand it correctly, is impossible with `numpy`  The array has to have the same number of columns per row.  With `pandas` you can construct multilevel indexing, and presumably use this `ID` as an index level.

We'll need your own sample, input and result, to do better.

===============

We could use `np.split` to break that sorted array into arrays with a common final column.  I chose `[2,4]` manually, but that can be derived from the data if you are interested.

```
In [39]: np.split(arr[idx,:],[2,4])
Out[39]: 
[array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), 
 array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
        [2, 1, 0, 0, 2]]), 
 array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
        [2, 2, 1, 2, 3]])]
```